# Force TabControl to load all TabItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a method which traverses through a `TabControl` to find children of specific types. When I call this method when only one `TabItem`has been selected  I only get the `Controls` of this `TabItem`. If I select every `TabItem` one time and call `FindVisualChildrenOfMultipleTypes()`, the `Controls` are loaded into the visual tree and I get the `Controls` of all `TabItems`. How can I force my `TabControl` to load all `TabItems`?

```
private void tabControlTest(System.Windows.Controls.TabControl tabControl)
{
    var tabControlView = View.GetParentView(tabControl);

    var types = new List<Type>()
    {
      typeof(CheckBox),
      typeof(RadioButton),
      typeof(TextBox)
    };

    tabControl.Template.LoadContent();
    tabControl.ApplyTemplate();
    tabControl.UpdateLayout();

    var children = UIHelper.FindVisualChildrenOfMultipleTypes(types, tabControl);      
}
```

UIHelper.cs method

```
public static IEnumerable<UIElement> FindVisualChildrenOfMultipleTypes(List<Type> types, DependencyObject dependencyObj)
{
    if (dependencyObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObj, i);
            if (child != null && types.Contains(child.GetType()))
            {
                yield return child as UIElement;
            }

            foreach (var childOfChild in FindVisualChildrenOfMultipleTypes(types, child))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I tried:

```
tabControl.Template.LoadContent();
tabControl.ApplyTemplate();
tabControl.UpdateLayout();
```

But none of these lines works.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Using e.g. MVVM you *almost* never have to traverse through visuals in order to get model (via ViewModel) items to do something.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm not interested in the model items but the UIElement items inside my TabControl

Comment: For what do you need `UIElement`s? Describe the [x problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295), there might be a solution which doesn't require doing it *complicated* way.

Comment: I need them because for every `UIElement` I log statistics (how many times is the field filled for example), now I want to retrieve this statistics from the database, but I need the UIElements in my TabControl to match with the elements saved in the database.

Comment: @Sinatr you know a less complicated way of doing this?

Comment: Of course there is an easy way. It is called MVVM. You don't care about `UIElement`s anymore, because each (e.g. `TextBox`) is bound to a property in ViewModel. So your statistic is easily organized inside those properties setters.

Comment: @Sinatr and without MVVM? Is there no way to force the TabControl to load all TabItems?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gather statistic like "how many times this value was changed", then it can be quite easily organized using MVVM. For beginning it's enough to start using bindings everywhere and never directly manipulate with UI.

Here is an example, how to count text changes, where *"text change"* is defined as different value in `TextBox` on focus lost (simplest case).

View:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" ... />
```

ViewModel:

```
class SomeTabPageViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
    string _someText;
    int _someTextChanged = 0; // how many times text was changed by user
    public string SomeText
    {
        get { return _someText; }
        set
        {
            _someText = value;
            _someTextChanged++; // when TextBox lost focus after user changed value
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

When ViewModel sets value of `SomeText` (for the first time or as a processing result) it should do it using field (otherwise counter is incremented, you don't want that), `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeText));` should be used to inform View update itself in this case.